# start Interval again after clearing it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I restart Interval after clearing it? I want a button to be clickable once every 11 seconds I made it disabled while timer is > 0 after it's equal to 0 button isn't disabled so it's clickable I wrote this code it seems to work but after multiple call of a `setInterval()` function timer goes down too fast any soltuions>

```js
  data:{
    sTimer:11,
    sDisabled:true,
    asd:null
  },
  methods:{
        testing(){
        this.sTimer--;
      if(this.sTimer == 0){
        clearInterval(this.asd);
        this.sTimer= 11;
        this.sDisabled = false;
      }else{
        this.sDisabled = true;
      }
    },
    specialAttack(){
      setInterval(() => this.testing(), 1000)
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.asd = setInterval(() => this.testing(), 1000);
  }
```

```html
<button class="specialAttack" :disabled="sDisabled" @click="specialAttack(); testing()">Special Attack {{ sTimer }}</button>
```

Comment: this is a little weird code imho, but you are starting the interval on created,. but if you call specialAttack from somewhere, you are als calling this.testing, which will cause the timer to count down faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes you made here, so first of all **to achieve such a thing you should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`** because interval generally will be repeated after a certain given time, so **this may one of the possible reason for being called twice** when you click your button as well. **Then you need to create a generic function for this cause and then call it in document creation** instead of creating two different intervals and calling them separately.

**So with respecting these rules**, your final code should be something like this:

HTML

```html
<button class="specialAttack" :disabled="sDisabled" @click="specialAttack();">Special Attack {{ sTimer }}</button>
```

Javascript

```js
data: () => {
    return {
      sTimer: 11,
      sDisabled: false,
      asd: null
    };
},
methods: {
    specialAttack() {
      clearTimeout(this.asd); // Or as you suggest in comments you can disbale it here with replacing this: this.sDisabled = true
      if (this.sTimer > 0) {
        this.asd = setTimeout(() => {
          this.sDisabled = true;
          this.sTimer -= 1;
          this.specialAttack();
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        clearTimeout(this.asd);
        this.sTimer = 11;
        this.sDisabled = false;
      }
    }
  },
created() {
    this.specialAttack();
}
```

Here is a working demo:

[image: CodeSandbox]

Comment: Works fine but, button is clickable for 1 second and within this 1 second I can click 5 times or more which's exactly what I don't want

Comment: I added `this.sDisabled = true` before if statement and it works fine. Thank you <3

Comment: @aravinvafshe Nice one, There is another way to fix this, so you should `clearTimeout` on each click. See the updates.